# Java - Trying to print all of the coincidences of a binary search

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search

This is my current search method:

```
public static int search(int[] array, int numero) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = array.length - 1;
    int center;

    while (start <= end) {
        center = (start + end) / 2;
        if (array[center] == numero) {
            return center;
        } else if (array[center] < numero) {
            start = center + 1;
        } else {
            end = center - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It searches from user input `numero` into a previously **bubble sorted** Array that's found in the Main method.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to print ALL of the coincidences found in the array, and not just the first one found.
I was thinking about adding results to a List and then returning that to Main, but as I tried that an endless loop happened at the first result found, causing it to add itself to the List repeatedly until the program crashes.

Comment: Your list approach could work, you just have to remember to also change the value of `start` or `end` when you add it - however you would have to check both 1 index on either side as `center` could land in the middle of a repeated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you know the basic theory behind binary searches, separate it into 3 steps.

1. Search using binary search methods.
2. once a match is found, scan up from that point, until you find a non matching element.
3. Scan down, adding to a result list, until you find a non
   matching element.

If you don't need to care about occurrence order, you could combine steps 2 and 3 and just scan up adding to the list, and scan down adding to the list, since due to the sorting, everything you hit is guaranteed to match until it doesn't.

If you *do* care about occurrence order, step 2 could be optimised by jumping ahead and checking, and writing a modified binary search that searches for a transition of matching/notmatching instead of a match.

This could be further optimised by keeping statistics or profiling, to find the perfect jump distance, or basing it off of the last up-most check.

Answer (score 0):

actually it's easy because the list is already sorted, the numbers you expect to find are adjacent.

just like Ryan's answer, I'll put some code

```
public static List<Integer> searchAll (int[] array, int numero){
int firstMatchIndex = search( array,  numero);
List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>():
results.add(firstMatchIndex);

boolean left = true;
while( left){
    int i = firstMatchIndex - 1;
    if(i<0 || array[i] != numero){
        left = false;
    }else{
        results.add(i);
    }
}

boolean right = true;
while( right){
    int i = firstMatchIndex + 1;
    if(i>array.length || array[i] != numero){
        right = false;
    }else{
        results.add(i);
    }
}
```

}